Setting Up SMS Notification API with wp_remote_post in WooCommerce when placing new & updating order
I have this free plugin for notifying users via SMS when there is an Order Status change/Order Note in WooCommerce, it is working well with the current API Integrated in codes below, So i need to twist it with another SMS Provider API and also i need when a user place a new order should also get SMS Notification
Below is the Simple Codes of a Plugin (CODE 1)
 <?php

/**
 * Plugin Name: Techipress SMS Notifier
 * Plugin URI: https://github.com/omukiguy/techiepress-sms-notifier
 * Author: Techipress
 * Author URI: https://github.com/omukiguy/techiepress-sms-notifier
 * Description: Send SMS Notifications from Woocommerce Order Notes and Order Status Changes.
 * Version: 0.0.1
 */
 
 // Event of a new email for the order - change in status
 add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'techiepress_send_sms_on_new_order_status', 10, 4 );
 
 // Event of the order note
 add_action( 'woocommerce_new_customer_note_notification', 'techiepress_send_sms_on_new_order_notes', 10, 1 );
 
 
 function techiepress_send_sms_on_new_order_status( $order_id, $old_status, $new_status, $order  ) {
     // Get the order Object
     $my_order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
     
     $firstname = $my_order->get_billing_first_name(); // firstname
     $phone     = $my_order->get_billing_phone(); // Phone
     $shopname  = get_option( 'woocommerce_email_from_name');
     
     $default_sms_message = "Thank you $firstname for shopping with $shopname. Your Order #$orderid is $new_status";
     
     techiepress_send_sms_to_customer( $phone, $default_sms_message, $shopname );
     
 }
 
 function techiepress_send_sms_on_new_order_notes( $email_args ) {
     
     $order = wc_get_order( $email_args['order_id'] );
     $note  = $email_args['customer_note'];
     
     $phone     = $order->get_billing_phone(); // Phone
     $shopname  = get_option( 'woocommerce_email_from_name');
     
     techiepress_send_sms_to_customer( $phone, $note, $shopname );
 }
 
 function techiepress_send_sms_to_customer( $phone = 'NULL', $default_sms_message, $shopname ) {
    
    if ( 'NULL' === $phone ) {
        return;
    }
    
    $msgdata = array(
        'method' => 'SendSms',
        'userdata' => array(
            'username' => 'Liz',
            'password' => 'Plugin',
        ),
        'msgdata' => array(
            array(
                'number' => $phone,
                'message' => $default_sms_message,
                'senderid' => $shopname,
            )
        )
    );
    
    $url = 'http://sms.sukumasms.com/api/v1/json/';

    $arguments = array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'body' => json_encode( $msgdata ),
    );

    $response = wp_remote_post( $url, $arguments );
    
    if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
        $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
        return "Something went wrong: $error_message";
    }
     
 }

This below is an API of a new SMS Provider For Post Request
Method-1:  Using POST Request (CODE 2)
Post Request JSON Format 
{ 
"api_id":   yourapiid, 
"api_password": yourapipassword, 
"sms_type": T, 
"encoding": T, 
"sender_id":  ASMSC, 
"phonenumber": 255714900900, 
"templateid": null, 
"textmessage":test message, 
"V1":   null, 
"V2":   null, 
"V3":   null, 
"V4":   null, 
"V5": null, 
"ValidityPeriodInSeconds":  60, 
"uid":"xyz", 
"callback_url":"https://example.com/", 
"pe_id":NULL, 
"template_id":NULL 
}

There Sample GET Format look like this
https://api.sprintsmsservice.com/api/SendSMS?api_id=APIUSERNAME&api_password=APIPASSWORD&sms_type=T&encoding=T&sender_id=ChonryOTP&phonenumber=255714892151&textmessage=test

And i think this is there URL
https://api.sprintsmsservice.com/api/SendSMS

So I'm seeking for a help on how to remove existing API in the Plugin Codes (CODE 1) and intergrate with a new SMS Provider API (CODE 2) as I'm not an expert with PHP and WooCommerce so any help will be appreciated
